# TSQL CREATE ASSEMBLY FROM varbinary breaks the class_name parameter

Tags: .net, sql-server, .net-assembly, sqlclr, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have migrated my on-premise SQL Server 2008 R2 databases to Azure SQL Server Managed Instance (SQL Server 2017). One database is an archive (read-only) database, one is the OLTP database, and the third is an utility database, where I keep generic functions, stored procedures, and maintenance scripts. Everything went very smoothly for all three DBs except for a CLR assembly in the utility DB. The assembly provides Regex functionality in TSQL code - very useful! I based it off of the Phil Factor code [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/). Originally it was loaded into an on-premise DB from the compiled DLL. It works like a champ there. But on SQL MI, I get the following error when running a SP that uses one of the CLR functions.

> Msg 10314, Level 16, State 11, Procedure dbo.globalSearch, Line 22 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   An error occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load assembly id 65541. The server may be running out of resources, or the assembly may not be trusted. Run the query again, or check documentation to see how to solve the assembly trust issues. For more information about this error:
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'regexsqlclr, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An error relating to security occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013150A)
>   System.IO.FileLoadException:
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString)

I've tried solving the assembly trust issues using the steps in [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2010/03/23/unable-to-load-clr-assembly-intermittently/) MSDN post, specifically executing

```
sys.sp_add_trusted_assembly
```

which succeeds, but changes nothing. Then I thought that since it is suggesting that it cannot load from file, which *seems* to make sense since the file does not exist in SQL MI where I have no access to the file system, that I should try dropping and recreating from `varbinary`. I only said that it *seems* to make sense because the file also does not exist on any of my other on-premise servers other than the one I originally loaded it from, and it works perfectly on all of them. But, I'm willing to try anything! So using SSMS I scripted out the assembly as `DROP` and `CREATE`, which uses the `FROM BINARY` syntax, and scripted out all of the functions likewise. `CREATE ASSEMBLY` succeeds, so I'm thinking I'm on the right track. Then I try to create the first function and BAM, another error! This time the error reads

> Msg 6505, Level 16, State 2, Procedure RegexIndex, Line 2
>   Could not find Type 'RegexSQLCLR.RegularExpressionFunctions' in assembly 'RegexFunctions'.

I've been Googling for hours trying to find a solution to that problem and have had zero luck. Even though that syntax for the class portion of the `EXTERNAL NAME` clause works perfectly for the assembly loaded from file. I verified that the `varbinary` scripted out by SSMS is identical to the binary of the original DLL. Someone on a Microsoft forum suggested that I make sure the DLL was compiled with the `Any CPU` option - it was. As a sanity check, I did the same procedure on one of the on-premise servers, i.e., `DROP` and `CREATE ASSEMBLY FROM BINARY`, and got the exact same result: I cannot load any of the CLR functions! I've tried every conceivable permutation of the class names that I can think of, to no avail. Here is the code for `CREATE ASSEMBLY` and `CREATE FUNCTION`

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [RegexFunction]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM 0x4D5A90000 *truncated_for_brevity*
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE

CREATE FUNCTION RegExIndex
   (
    @Pattern NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Options int
   )
RETURNS int
AS EXTERNAL NAME 
   RegexFunction.[RegexSQLCLR.RegularExpressionFunctions].RegExIndex
GO
```

`RegexSQLCLR` is the name of the original DLL and `RegularExpressionFunctions` is the name of the class. `RegexSQLCLR` is also the name specified in the `name` column of `sys.assembly_files` after using `CREATE ASSEMBLY FROM BINARY`; the full path to the original DLL is in the `name` column otherwise.

Comment: While we are trying to figure this out, why don't you try installing the SQLCLR library that I created, [SQL#](https://sqlsharp.com/?ref=so_54953930), as it contains quite a few RegEx functions and plenty of other stuff. You don't need all of the assemblies, so you can set some to "0" in the section just below the header comment (such as `Network`, `OS`, `Twitterizer`), and `@MaxAllowedAccessLevel = 1`.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky thanks I will take a look at it. By the way I did find the answer (see below). That's two days I'll never get back! At least that made the original CLR work. But I'm still curious about why `CREATE ASSEMBLY FROM BINARY` breaks the syntax of the `EXTERNAL NAME` clause on both Managed Instance and SQL Server 2008 R2. If anyone has an answer for that I would love to hear it! In all the searching I did I've yet to find anyone posting an example of `CREATE ASSEMBLY FROM BINARY` that actually works.

Comment: Ron, no, `TRUSTWORTHY ON` is _not_ the answer...._ever_....did you restore these DBs to a managed instance? why are you re-loading the SQLCLR stuff?...if it was because of the security error, that is easy enough to fix without reloading..but still need to understand exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I used the Azure SQL Migration Service to load the DBs to MI. So that's not really a traditional restore, per se. I was reloading the SQLCLR because I was running out of ideas. If you know of another way to fix the security issue without `TRUSTWORTHY ON` I would love to hear it.

Comment: I am posting an answer now...but it's not short :( mainly because of multiple issues here resulting from the various attempts at fixing this..

Answer (score 1):

So, there are a series of issues here:

1. The first issue is that unsigned assemblies (or even signed assemblies that do not also have a matching, signature-based login that has been granted the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission) are no longer considered "SAFE" due to *potential* (but possibly unproven) security concerns. So, starting in SQL Server 2017, a new server level config setting called "CLR strict security" was introduced and forces *all* assemblies to meet the requirements of assemblies marked as `UNSAFE`. The `PERMISSION_SET` options of `SAFE` and `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` still work as before, this is just an issue for loading assemblies and executing SQLCLR objects from them. The problem you ran into was that `SAFE` assemblies never needed to be signed (though they could have been, such as all of the assemblies in my [SQL#](https://sqlsharp.com/?ref=so_54954329) SQLCLR library, and there are benefits to signing them, even if they only contain `SAFE` code and will remain as `PERMISSION_SET = SAFE`) and so most were not signed, yet now they need to be. So, upon upgrading / migrating a DB from pre-2017 to SQL Server 2017 or newer, a security error is thrown.

One option is to simply disable "CLR strict security", or another option is to enable `TRUSTWORTHY` for the DB where the assembly lives. Both are less secure options. I'm not sure how "insecure" having "CLR strict security" disabled really is (in practice, it could be a huge overreaction on Microsoft's part), but clearly the preference is to keep that enabled. Enabling `TRUSTWORTHY` is definitely a *very* bad option: [PLEASE, Please, please Stop Using Impersonation, TRUSTWORTHY, and Cross-DB Ownership Chaining](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/12/30/please-please-please-stop-using-impersonation-execute-as/).

The mechanism that Microsoft released in order to address this situation is the "trusted assemblies" feature. Unfortunately, that feature is also a bad option: it was very much never needed (well, only needed for Azure SQL Database, which no longer supports SQLCLR, but the "trusted assemblies" code had already been written) and was only made visible because nobody understood that existing functionality already addressed this situation, and in a much better way. [Please see: SQLCLR vs. SQL Server 2017, Part 4: “Trusted Assemblies” - The Disappointment](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/28/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-4-trusted-assemblies-the-disappointment/). That post goes into detail as to the problems with "trusted assemblies" and how you *should* fix the problem of existing, unsigned assemblies (i.e. create a certificate in the DB with the assembly, sign the assembly, create the same certificate in `master` from the public key only, create a login from the certificate in master, and finally grant that login the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission).

1. > I've tried solving the assembly trust issues using ... `sys.sp_add_trusted_assembly` which succeeds, but changes nothing.

I'm not sure what value you used for the hash, but that stored procedure doesn't verify that the hash matches anything. It just loads the hash into an internal table to be read from later when an assembly is referenced. Then it will see if the assembly's hash value matches a value in that internal table of stored hashes. So it should pretty much always succeed (as long as you gave it a valid binary value that could be a SHA2_256 hash).

1. > I thought that since it is suggesting that it cannot load from file, which seems to make sense since the file does not exist in SQL MI where I have no access to the file system

This is just a misinterpretation. You are correct that there is no file system access in Azure SQL Database Managed Instances, but the file system in this case is the internal table that is storing the assembly that was loaded via `CREATE ASSEMBLY`. The error is saying that the assembly cannot be loaded from the table into memory. And this was due to the security issue noted above in item # 1. So dropping and re-creating the assembly doesn't actually do anything.

1. > Someone on a Microsoft forum suggested that I make sure the DLL was compiled with the Any CPU option

I have no idea why that even came up. Again, nothing was wrong with any of the code here.

1. > `AS EXTERNAL NAME  RegexFunction.[RegexSQLCLR.RegularExpressionFunctions].RegExIndex`

Not sure why `RegexSQLCLR` was put in there, but the format is (no namespace):

`AssemblyName.ClassName.MethodName`

or (with namespace):

`AssemblyName.[NameSpaceName.ClassName].MethodName`

1. Again, `TRUSTWORTHY ON` is a [bad choice, and entirely unnecessary](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/12/30/please-please-please-stop-using-impersonation-execute-as/).

Comment: Thank you Solomon for all your help.
"I'm not sure what value you used for the hash,"
This code:
`DECLARE @hash_bytes varbinary(64);

SELECT @hash_bytes=HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 0x4D5A90000{truncated for brevity})

EXEC sys.sp_add_trusted_assembly @hash=@hash_bytes, @description=N'regexsqlclr, version=0.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=null, processorarchitecture=msil'`
According to the documentation in your referenced link and elsewhere, SHA2_512 is required for the hash. Is that not correct?

Comment: @CB_Ron Hmm...that does _appear_ to be correct, assuming that the `0x4D5A...` part was the 100% complete and exact same binary string that was used for the `CREATE ASSEMBLY` statement. I have never used the `@description` parameter as it is optional, so maybe try again with leaving that off? Also, did you get a chance to test installing the Free version of [SQL#](https://sqlsharp.com/?ref=db_54954329)? Just curious if it has any install problems. Last time I checked it wasn't easy to get a test account, but it looks like they added dev/test pricing in mid-December, so I'll look into that too.